C# console ввод текста без переноса курсора
Возникла такая проблема, при заполнении строки курсор переходит на след строку и если буфер консоли заполнен он его увеличивает. Вопрос, как избежать этого?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1262561/373567 оно?

А других вариантов реализации нет?

что именно не так? вы бы хоть начали разбираться, не знаю, чем вас напугали 10 строчек кода.

Просто интересно, может есть варианты без использования апи.

Если бы были, я бы наверное их описал в том ответе.

Ясно, спасибо за помощь.
